# Why ridge regression minimizes test cost when lambda is negative

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, regression

I am processing a set of data using ridge regression. I found a very interesting phenomenon when apply the learned function to data.  Namely, when the ridge parameter increases from zero, the test error keeps increasing. But if we penalize small coefficients(set the parameter <0), the test error can even be smaller.

This is my matlab code:

```
for i = 1:100
  beta = ridgePolyRegression(ty_train,tX_train,lambda(i));
  sqridge_train_cost(i) =  computePolyCostMSE(ty_train,tX_train,beta);
  sqridge_test_cost(i) = computePolyCostMSE(ty_valid,tX_valid,beta);
end
plot(lambda,sqridge_test_cost,'color','b');
```

lambda is the ridge parameter. ty_train is the output of the training data, tX_train is the input of training data. Also, we use a quadratic function regression here.

```
function [ beta ] = ridgePolyRegression( y,tX,lambda )
X = tX(:,2:size(tX,2));
tX2 = [tX,X.^2];
beta = (tX2'*tX2 + lambda * eye(size(tX2,2))) \ (tX2'*y);
end
```

The plotted picture is: [image: plot]

Why the error is minimal when lambda is negative? Is it a sign of under-fitting?

Comment: I suggest you to ask this question either at http://stats.stackexchange.com/ or at http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A strongly related question on cross-validated:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/328630/is-ridge-regression-useless-in-high-dimensions-n-ll-p-how-can-ols-fail-to

Answer (score 2):

You should not use negative lambdas.

From (probabilistic) theoretic point of view, lambda relates to the inverse of variance of parameter prior distribution, and variance can't be negative.

From computational point of view, it can (given it's less that the smallest eigenvalue of the covariance matrix) turn your positive-definite form into an indefinite form, which means you'll have not a maximum, but a saddle point. It also means there are points where your target function is as small (or as big) as you want, so you can reduce loss indefinitely and no minimum / maximum exists at all.

Your optimization algorithm gives you just a stationary point, which will be a global maximum if and only if the form is positive definite.

Comment: I just want to understand why negative lambdas give even smaller test error. It seems ridiculous...

Comment: There are cases when n<<p where the optimal lambda (optimal in terms of test/validation error) is negative: https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.10939

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**: When *lambda* is negative, you're actually overfitting your data. Hence, it's reasonable to get much less error.

**Long Answer**:

The regularization term (or the **penalty term** as described by many statisticians) aims to penalize the weights (or the betas as written in the coming Eq.) for going too high *(overfitting)* and going too low *(underfitting)*. Giving you the power to control how your model behaves, and you usually aim the *"right fitting"* model.

For mathematical intuition, you can check the following Eq. (P. S. Equation is screenshotted from Elements of Statistical Learning by Trevor Hastie et. al)

[image]

When you decide to make your *lambda* negative, the penalty term is indeed turned into a **utility term** that helps to increase the weights (i.e., overfitting).

Overfitting is, simply, understanding your data along with the features more than you should, because you do not have the whole population yet; therefore, what you understood so far is possibly wrong on a different dataset.

So, *you should never* be using negative values of lambdas.